# How to calculate categorical omega reliability coefficient when some items only have one value?

Tags: r, reliability, confirmatory-factor, lavaan

From what I understand, running omega reliability in R is quite straightforward, even for binary responses. However, I've encountered a situation when running this command:

```
#### Load Libraries ####
library(lavaan)
library(psych)

#### Fit Variables ####
mod.abc <- '
ABC_Variable =~ ABC_01 + ABC_02 + ABC_03 + ABC_04 + ABC_05 +
ABC_06 + ABC_07 + ABC_08 + ABC_09 + ABC_10 +
ABC_11 + ABC_12 + ABC_13 + ABC_14 + ABC_15 +
ABC_16 + ABC_17 + ABC_18 + ABC_19 + ABC_20 
'

#### Run CFA for Omega ####
fit <- cfa(mod.abc,
             data=data,
             std.lv=T,
             ordered=T,
             estimator='WLSMV')
```

The function spits back an error:

```
Error in lav_data_full(data = data, group = group, cluster = cluster,  : 
  lavaan ERROR: ordered variable(s) has/have only 1 level
```

Checking the variables, the problem is quite clear. The data shows that two variables only have 1's, whereas every other variable has at least a 0 or 1 value. What should be done in this situation? Should the two variables be removed (I would think not)? Is there another option in `lavaan` that can bypass this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> two variables only have 1's

Then they are not variables, they are constants.  They cannot be modeled, and creating a composite that includes them would simply shift the value to the right by a constant.  The only solutions are to leave out the constants or gather a sufficiently large sample that some unlikely 0s are observed.

Comment: Removing them from the model sounds like a reasonable alternative. Do you know any references that would support this decision? I wouldn't want to do so without having a way to justify it on paper.

Comment: No citation necessary.  You literally have no other alternative.  You cannot model a constant.  It has no variance to be explained.  You can still include it in your composite, but that would only change its mean, not the (proportion of) common-factor variance.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks.